# How to "echo off" the serial port in java

Tags: java, serial-port, echo

I am using java comm library for serial port communication in my application. When I put some data on output stream, after sometime the same command is displayed on input stream of serial port. Do anybody has any idea how to echo off the serial port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that the receiver sends back your data. If you have something connected, verify 'echo on' settings on the other side.

If it is the case, you could use this echo to constantly check the communication line.